# How to to use find with Object.entries()?

Tags: typescript

I have object contain these data

```
{
    'c':'d',
    'd':'a',
    'e':'f',
}
```

I am trying to use the array `find()` like this

```
let found = Object.entries(myobject).find(item => item['d'] == 'a');
```

but I get undefined for `found` value so how I should write this ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns **array of pairs**, where the first element of each pair is **key**, and the second element is **value**. So the callback in [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will receive `pair` as argument, and then you can check its key (`pair[0]`) and value (`pair[1]`):

```js
const myObject = {
  'c': 'd',
  'd': 'a',
  'e': 'f',
}

const found = Object.entries(myObject)
  .find(pair => pair[0] === 'd' && pair[1] === 'a');

console.log(found);
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) in function parameter:

```js
const myObject = {
  'c': 'd',
  'd': 'a',
  'e': 'f',
}

const found = Object.entries(myObject)
  .find(([key, value]) => key === 'd' && value === 'a');

console.log(found);
```